# 7165X786 size of large image could't be display in real device(Tablets)

Tags: java, android, imageview, large-files

I am having trouble of displaying the large image into android. I have tried to get this done by this [custom- scrollable-image-view](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/custom-scrollable-image-view) .

I have used full View in my class and used the 7165*786 size of image into it. And it is of only 1.11MB of image.  I am able to run this code in bluestack and see the image in it but it couldn't be load in real device.

```
bmLargeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.imagewithout);
bmlotusImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.lotus);
```

I am using the same canvas in onDraw methow as below.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmLargeImage, scrollRect, displayRect, paint);

canvas.drawBitmap(bmlotusImage1, 45 - newScrollRectX,
                255 - newScrollRectY, paint);
```

i could not be able to display the bmlargeImage in my real device i can see the lotus image on Device but not the large one.

Should i have to decode or scale the image or anything else to get it display in real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the solution of not Displaying the image in real Device the problem was the simply.

I have just removed the target sdk a i get the error in webservice. It start showing the image to my real device also and also i get the solution for Displaying the image FIt to screen as below.

```
private static Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(String backgroundimage, int width,
        int height) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(backgroundimage,
            bmpFactoryOptions);

    int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight
            / (float) height);
    int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth
            / (float) width);

    if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
        }
    }

    bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(backgroundimage, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;

}
```

And i have passed the image width adn height as the parameter in this method.

```
bmLargeImage = ShrinkBitmap(backgroundimage, 7165, 786);
```